# Django: `model.fk_id` isn't updated after `model.fk.save()`?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.3

I've got a model which, when saved, should create and save one of its foreign keys if it doesn't already exist:

```
class MyModel(m.Model):
    fk = m.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)

    def save(self):
        if not self.fk_id:
            self.fk = AnotherModel()
            self.fk.save()
        return super(MyModel, self).save()
```

But the call to `super(MyModel, self).save()` raises an error, because `self.fk_id` is still null:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ".../models.py", line 10, in save
    return super(MyModel, self).save()
  ...
  File ".../django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 44, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
IntegrityError: null value in column "fk_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Note: a debugger shows that `self.fk.id` has been set correctly, and everything seems to work when `self.fk_id = self.fk.id` is added.

So, my question: why is `self.fk_id = self.fk.id` necessary? And is it possible to avoid doing that explicitly?

Comment: Why not save the AnotherModel object before assigning it to `self.fk`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman ah, hadn't considered that. I suppose that would work… But still doesn't "make sense".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8892) is your answer. Currently, you just need to set the related object after it has a primary key itself. They're still discussing the patch.